# SQL query to append comma with successor value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I need to get the immediate successor as comma using SQL Query.

I tried ListAGG function, but did not getting expected output.

**Scenario**:

[image]

Comment: I actually answered this exact question 2 days ago, q.v. the duplicate link.  If you can't use my answer, then state why and I can remove the duplicate mark.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen,  just now i got to know that it was answered.